# How many five digit positive integer numbers are possible that each of the digits but the last one, is $\ge$ the next digit?

Tags: combinatorics

How many five digit positive integer numbers are possible that each of the digits but the last one, is $\ge$ the next digit?

How do I approach this problem?

Comment: @brianmscott unrestricted

Comment: @brianmscott 10000 I think

Comment: If I understand your problem correctly, you need to count numbers of the form $\overline{abcde}$ where $a\geq b\geq c\geq d\geq e$ and $a\neq 0$ and $a,b,c,d,e$ are one-digit numbers. Right?

Comment: I couldn't interpret this problem either

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let it be $abcde$ then $13\ge a+4>b+3>c+2>d+1>e\ge0$ so it is equal to the ways to choose $5$ different numbers out of $14$.

Therefore $\dbinom{14}{5} = 2002$

However since $a=b=c=d=e=0$ forms $00000$ which cannot work since it is not positive. We are left with $2002-1=2001$

The following program also provided similar results:

```
Dim counter As Integer = 0

For n = 10000 To 99999

    Dim a As String = n.ToString

    Dim a_char() = a.ToCharArray

    If ((a(0) >= a(1)) And (a(1) >= a(2)) And (a(2) >= a(3)) And (a(3) >= a(4))) Then

        counter = counter + 1

    End If

Next

Console.WriteLine(counter)

Console.ReadLine()
```

Comment: This is off by at least $1$, since it allows $00000$ as a solution. It may be off by considerably more, if leading zeros are not allowed. Oh, and it’s also off by not allowing arbitrary $e$.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Wouldn't the solution 00000 work because it meets the conditions to the problem though?

Comment: It doesn’t: it’s not positive.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Yep, youre right

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Is that fine?

Comment: Yes, that’s fine; I misread part of the problem statement and made the problem harder than it should have been.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott So I'm correct?

Comment: @BrianM.Scott I also ran a program that gave 2001 as well.

Comment: You are indeed.

Answer (score 1):

If $abcde$ is the integer,

let $t_1=a-b, \;\;t_2=b-c,\;\; t_3=c-d, \;\;t_4=d-e,\;\; t_5=e, \text{ and }t_6=9-a$.

The number of integers corresponds to the number of solutions of $t_1+\cdots+t_6=9$ with $t_i\ge0$ and $t_6\ne9$,

so it is given by $\binom{14}{5}-1=2001$.